# Gold Value Glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I find gold in chests or in other people's pockets, it displays the value of the coin as 2000, no matter the amount of coins. Here is an image of the issue.

[image: The value is 2000, but there is only 9 gold.]

I noticed this about a day ago in real time, but I'm not sure when I started to see it. If I take the gold, it adds the actual value of gold to my inventory. I know this has no affect on game play, but it is sort of annoying to see the 2000 next to value. It gets me excited every time, but then I see the actual amount of gold. I have all the official DLC. I am subscribed to several mods on Steam. Since I'm not sure if the mods are the cause of the problem, here is a list of the mods I have:

- Pure Waters
- Skyrim Weather Beautification
- HD Plants + Herbs
- Enhanced Blood Textures 3.6b
- Sexy NPC Faces Mod
- New Loading Screens
- Sexy Flora and Fauna Mod
- Weightless Books
- Followers Keep Up
- Dragonborn's Home Bigger on the Inside (Doctor Who)

**Edit:** I have tried turning off all of my mods and I still encounter this issue.

Comment: Have you tried turning off all of your mods, and seeing if the problem is still there?

Comment: Chances are insanely good that one of your mods is causing the problem.

Comment: I turned off all my mods, then I reloaded the save. Gold's value is still shown at 2000 @B.S.Morganstein

Comment: Turn off your mods and start a new game.  Your mods probably permanently screwed up your world by changing the coin values.

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered this problem, which means one of your mods is messing with the game, OR you have a script failure. When the script is screwed up, that means reinstall the game

Answer (score -3):

Since items have a price, gold even has a value too. But since gold is what you pay for, they just put a random amount. Don't worry about the value the gold has. Bethesda just wants to put something odd since gold is what you pay for. If a you downloaded any mods, delete them to see if that changes. otherwise, if you have the [Skyrim Creation Kit](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Creation_Kit), check the gold amount and change it.

Comment: This isn't even correct.  In a normal game the value of 1 gold is 1.